# CSS Gaps between images when those are placed in Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn CSS. I want to write approximation of tesla.com website.

1. I have placed all the images in the flexbox (each image is in separate div)
2. I want to remove gaps between those images.
3. I have checked multiple post here in stackoverflow.
4. I have also googled the question but no relevant answer has come up.

Please advice if you can.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Electric Cars, Solar & Clean Energy</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <style>
        body {
 
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        p {
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 0%;
            margin-right:0 !important;
        }
        .item {
            flex-grow: 1;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin-right:0 !important;
        }
        .item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p div="impact_report">Read Tesla's 2021 Impact Report</p>
    <div class="class">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="M3-Homepage-Desktop-LHD.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="Desktop-ModelY.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="Homepage-Model-X-Desktop-LHD.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="_25-HP-SolarPanels-D.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="HP-SR-Design-D.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="dd739764-bcaa-4263-9488-8c73bc9fb046.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Electric Cars, Solar & Clean Energy</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <style>
        body {
 
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        p {
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            display: grid;
            margin-right:0 !important;
            grid-gap: 0;

        }
        .item {
            
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin-right:0 !important;
        }
        .item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p div="impact_report">Read Tesla's 2021 Impact Report</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="M3-Homepage-Desktop-LHD.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="Desktop-ModelY.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="Homepage-Model-X-Desktop-LHD.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="_25-HP-SolarPanels-D.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="HP-SR-Design-D.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="dd739764-bcaa-4263-9488-8c73bc9fb046.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need for the pictures to be in the column not in the row. I have tried to change that but when done, those tiny spaces appear again. Sorry for the delay, it was one busy week.

Comment: i change it to grid instead of flex. see above edit. let me know if it is still gving you some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Electric Cars, Solar & Clean Energy</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <style>
    
    .class::after{
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
        body {
 
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        p {
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 0%;
            margin-right:0 !important;
        }
        .item {


              float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
        }
        .item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Read Tesla's 2021 Impact Report</p>
    <div class="class">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="M3-Homepage-Desktop-LHD.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="Desktop-ModelY.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="Homepage-Model-X-Desktop-LHD.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="_25-HP-SolarPanels-D.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="HP-SR-Design-D.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="dd739764-bcaa-4263-9488-8c73bc9fb046.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```